# C++ подключение библиотеки собранной из исходников

Tags: c++, ide, mingw

Помогите разобраться с подключением библиотеки.

Я собрал библиотеку из исходников, в результате получил некоторую иерархию файлов и папок, официальная инструкция по установке библиотеки на этом заканчивается. Если библиотека состоит из папок lib, include, bin, то как подключить ее понятно. Но тут получается более сложная структура файлов и папок. Как подключить библиотеку в подобных случаях?

Пытаюсь подключить библиотеку Wt, компилятор MinGW, если это важно.

Comment: Все правильно сделали, осталось сделать install. В случае генератора MSVC, надо собрать проект `INSTALL`.

Comment: Из другого CMake-проекта делаете `find_library()`/`find_directory()`, чтобы найти эти либы и хедеры, и `include_directories()`/`target_link_libraries()` их.

Comment: Для `Wt` вообще готовый модуль есть. Если текст ошибки не сказал ничего полезного, то откройте файл `FindWt.cmake`, там будет написано какие переменные надо установить.